# Vectorized and looped versions return different answers

Tags: r, igraph

I am running a product diffusion simulation study. The simulation begins with a network of nodes and seeds an small initial number of nodes with a product. Diffusion beyond the seeding stage is governed by a probability rule, that depends on the number of neighbors of the node who have adopted the product. I wrote two versions of this model in R - one vectorized and the other with loops. The idea is probably better expressed in code.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(20130810)

g <- sample_smallworld(dim = 1, size = 1000, nei = 12, p = 0.6)

n.nodes <- length(V(g))
nbr.influence <- rnorm(n = n.nodes, mean = 0.18, sd = 0.01)

# Diffusion simulation with loops

nodes.status <- rep.int(0, n.nodes)
seed <- sample(V(g), size = as.integer(0.005*n.nodes))
nodes.status[seed] <- 1

cat("Number of nodes seeded (loop version): ", sum(nodes.status), "\n")

for (node in V(g)) {
  if (nodes.status[node] != 1) {
    n.active.nbrs = 0

    for (nbr in neighbors(g, node)) {
      if (nodes.status[nbr] == 1) n.active.nbrs <- n.active.nbrs + 1
    }

    prob.change <- 1 - (1 - nbr.influence[node])^n.active.nbrs

    if (runif(n = 1) < prob.change) nodes.status[node] = 1
  }
}

cat("Number of nodes engaged after one iteration (loop version): ", 
sum(nodes.status), "\n")

# Vectorized diffusion simulation 

A <- get.adjacency(g)

nodes.status <- rep.int(0, n.nodes)
seed <- sample(V(g), size = as.integer(0.005*n.nodes))
nodes.status[seed] <- 1
cat("Number of nodes seeded (vectorized version): ", sum(nodes.status), "\n")

# use the adjacency matrix to count number of active neighbors for each node
n.active.neighbours <- as.vector(A %*% nodes.status)

# build the activation probability vector
prob.change <- 1 - (1 - nbr.influence)^n.active.neighbours

# see which of the nodes are ready to activate
vuln.nodes <- runif(n = n.nodes) < prob.change

# activate those nodes which are ready
nodes.status[vuln.nodes > nodes.status] <- 1

cat("Number of nodes engaged after one iteration (vectorized version): ", 
sum(nodes.status), "\n")
```

Running this code gives the following output

```
Number of nodes seeded (loop version):  5 
Number of nodes engaged after one iteration (loop version):  380 
Number of nodes seeded (vectorized version):  5 
Number of nodes engaged after one iteration (vectorized version):  32
```

The logic of both versions is the same (i.e. diffusion is by the same probability rule), but the final answers are widely different. Where is the mistake in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop and "vectorised" version are doing two very different things. On all of the 1000 iterations of your `for` loop, you update (always increasing, or at least not decreasing) the the activation probability vector. In the vectorised version, all 1000 iterations are done "at the same time" so the probabilities are all calculated using the same vector.

For example, on the first iteration of the for loop, you calculate the probability that the first node gets updated. If it does, then it can affect the probability the the second node gets updated. In the vectorised version, the probability that the second node gets updated is not affected whether or not the first node gets updated.

If you want to make both the same, you have to make your `for` loop preserve the original state of all other node when you calculate the new status. Here is an example:

```
cat("Number of nodes seeded (loop version): ", sum(nodes.status), "\n")

new.nodes.status <- nodes.status # copy vector to preserve original state.
for (node in V(g)) {
  if (nodes.status[node] != 1) {
    n.active.nbrs = 0
    for (nbr in neighbors(g, node)) {
      if (nodes.status[nbr] == 1) n.active.nbrs <- n.active.nbrs + 1
    }
    prob.change <- 1 - (1 - nbr.influence[node])^n.active.nbrs
    if (runif(n = 1) < prob.change) new.nodes.status[node] = 1 # Only update new.
  }
}

cat("Number of nodes engaged after one iteration (loop version): ", 
    sum(new.nodes.status), "\n")
```

Which gets me `32`. But you should also set your seed before each run to get exactly the same thing.

Comment: Very clear explanation! I understand the code much better now!